# Boost Shared Memory - Returning Vector of Pointers

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory

I'm using a boost::interprocess::mapped_region to hold a fixed array of `structs` which I share between different processes. This works fine, I access these structs by an ID offset.

E.g.

```
Container_Struct* container = (Container_Struct*)mapped_region.get_address()
```

where `Container_Struct` contains an array of another struct which I can access by offset.

E.g.

```
MyData* data = container->dataArray[0];
```

I know this is not the most elegant way of handling sharing data but I'm only a beginner with boost interprocess and using maps etc. isn't all clear to me.

Now what I want to do is return a list/vector of pointers to a number of MyData struct to different processes.

I obviously cant simply use a `std::vector<MyData*>` container because a vector is temporary and invalid among processes.

How would I go to create a temporary vector of pointers to `MyData` struct ? I can't simply create another region to hold vectors in it because that would not be thread safe if multiple processes request a vector of pointers - I also don't want any overhead with locking read because currently the data shared is only read and never written from any process - thus there is no sync/lock needed.

Lets say I want to add a function to my shared lib that will give me a vector of `MyData*` Pointers based on a list of index `int`s, where index is the offset in the Container_Struct - how would i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You'd use a vector `boost::interprocess::offset_ptr` to share pointers inside the memory segment in such a way that the pointers are usable across processes, e.g.:

```
template <typename T>
using Ptr = boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<T>;

template <typename T>
using SharedVector = std::vector<
      Ptr<T>,
      boost::interprocess::allocator<Ptr<T>, boost::interprocess::shared_memory_segment::segment_manager>;
```

Of course you **need** to have the actual T's pointed to also in the same memory segment for `offset_ptr` to be able to work.

It looks, by now, that you'd actually be better of using

- boost::multi_index_container (which can main (multiple) indices to a container) and understands Boost Interprocess allocators just fine
- Boost Intrusive containers (which can form a collection of "simple" objects that live "somewhere else"). The builtin Intrusive Hooks understand how to use `boost::interprocess::offset_ptr` just fine

Comment: I cant follow you - i already can share the pointers accross processes easily by just calling  container->dataArray[0] because they are all mapped in mapped_region.get_address() - my problem is - how do i return a temporary list of specific entries (pointers) of that array basic on a query (like give my all pointers to MyData where myData.valX = 2

Comment: I'm sorry. I interpreted this as something more complicated. If your problem is not with sharing pointers into shared memory, then I don't see what's specific. In fact, the container you wish to return is pretty much the same thing as the container you describe in your question.

Comment: Perhaps you can simplify and just pass a list of indexes into the array instead of addresses. Although I don't see how this would essentially change the task.